# Index Error: index 512 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 512

Tags: python, arrays, image, indexing, opencv

So, I'm trying to replicate the "Floyd–Steinberg dithering" on an image, in python, and so far this what I have donne:

```
import cv2

# returns an array with rgb values of all pixels
x_img = cv2.imread("lenac.tif")

# returns an image with the rgb values turned to black and white
x_img_g = cv2.cvtColor(x_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



def dither(img):

    col = len(img[0])
    li = len(img)

    print(col)
    print(li)

    for i in range (li):
        for j in range(col):

            oldpixel = img[li][col]
            newpixel = quantificacao(oldpixel)

            print(newpixel)

print(dither(x_img_g))
```

So basically the method is not finished and the only thing it is doing, is going trough every and each pixel of a black and white version on the "lena.tif" image (very famous in image manipulation), and aplying to them a method called "quantificacao", irrelevant to the question.

The image is, 512 x 512

Everything goes fine, until at a given point the following error pops up:

```
oldpixel = img[li][col]

IndexError: index 512 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 512
```

Both the variables `col` and `li`, are shown to be 512, so, the `for cycle` should go from 0 to 511 right?

Therefore only indexing till 511

I'm kinda lost in these one, and would be extremely garteful if someone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `dither` function, you are attempting to iterate over the axes of your `img` and extract the value into the variable `oldpixel`. `li` and `col` correspond to the sizes of the `img` array; `i` and `j` are your variables which increment from `0` up to the length of each axis (both of which are 512). Therefore, inside your `for` loop, you should be using these variables, rather than `li` and `col`, i.e.:

```
for i in range(li):
    for j in range(col):
        oldpixel = img[i][j]
```

You may make this clearer by inlining the temporary variables `li` and `col`:

```
for i in range (len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        oldpixel = img[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

of course you're having that error, `li`, and `col` has value of 512, and on the loop you're accessing that value. `img[li][col]` should be `img[i][j]`.